# AWS elasticache - Redis: Unable to debug for Redis errors

Tags: node.js, redis, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

We are implementing caching using AWS Elasticache with Redis and are using nodejs for connecting it with the Redis. Creating a sorted set and adding and getting elements to and from it. It is working fine on local machine, while not working on Staging. Here is the code,

```
const redis = require("redis")
const redisOption = {
    host: redis_host_url,
    port: redis_port
}
let client = redis.createClient(redisOption);
console.log(client);
client = promisify(client.zadd).bind(client);
console.log(client);
let response = await client("abc",1,"string_to_add");
console.log(response);
```

Getting response printed on local machine, but Lambda logs does not contain the last console. Client is:

```
RedisClient {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { newListener: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  address: 'XXXXXXXXXX:6379',
  connection_options: { port: 6379, host: 'XXXXXXXXXX', family: 4 },
  connection_id: 0,
  connected: false,
  ready: false,
  should_buffer: false,
  command_queue:
   Denque {
     _head: 0,
     _tail: 0,
     _capacityMask: 3,
     _list: [ <4 empty items> ] },
  offline_queue:
   Denque {
     _head: 0,
     _tail: 0,
     _capacityMask: 3,
     _list: [ <4 empty items> ] },
  pipeline_queue:
   Denque {
     _head: 0,
     _tail: 0,
     _capacityMask: 3,
     _list: [ <4 empty items> ] },
  connect_timeout: 3600000,
  enable_offline_queue: true,
  retry_timer: null,
  retry_totaltime: 0,
  retry_delay: 200,
  retry_backoff: 1.7,
  attempts: 1,
  pub_sub_mode: 0,
  subscription_set: {},
  monitoring: false,
  message_buffers: false,
  closing: false,
  server_info: {},
  auth_pass: undefined,
  selected_db: undefined,
  fire_strings: true,
  pipeline: false,
  sub_commands_left: 0,
  times_connected: 0,
  buffers: false,
  options:
   { host: XXXXXXXXXX,
     port: 6379,
     socket_keepalive: true,
     socket_initial_delay: 0,
     return_buffers: false,
     detect_buffers: false },
  reply: 'ON',
  reply_parser:
   JavascriptRedisParser {
     optionReturnBuffers: false,
     optionStringNumbers: false,
     returnError: [Function: returnError],
     returnFatalError: [Function: returnFatalError],
     returnReply: [Function: returnReply],
     offset: 0,
     buffer: null,
     bigStrSize: 0,
     totalChunkSize: 0,
     bufferCache: [],
     arrayCache: [],
     arrayPos: [] },
  stream:
   Socket {
     connecting: true,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        reading: false,
        onread: [Function: onStreamRead],
        onconnection: null,
        [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular] },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: true,
        paused: false,
        emitClose: false,
        autoDestroy: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        end: [Array],
        connect: [Function],
        data: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Function],
        drain: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: false,
        autoDestroy: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: null,
     _server: null,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 7,
     [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
     [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
     [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 } }
```

Even console after the promisify is working, and is printing:

```
[Function: bound zadd]
```

But the last console is not printing anything. I am not able to debug as, AWS Elasticache doesn't offer logs for Redis.

Comment: are you timing out from lambda?

Comment: @LostJon No, lambda's timeout is the default value. I have not specified timeout explicitly. But in Lambda logs I am getting, `Task timed out after 6.01 seconds`

Comment: so..you "are" getting a timeout. everything here points to a network issue. make sure your lambda has network access to the redis instance...you may need to configure lambda to use the same VPC as your redis, if its not publicly accessible

Comment: @LostJon Yes, most probably this is the issue. I am heading towards this direction. Even set-up Redis on EC2  and tried to connect. Still, getting the same issue. There is a problem with VPC and access rights.

Comment: configure your lambda to be in the same VPC as your EC2, then configure the Security Gateway on your EC2 to allow all traffic from that VPC.

Comment: @LostJon I configured lambda and EC2 in same VPC and allowed 'All traffic' on security group applied on Lambda. Still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a bastion host in your AWS setup and locally in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host your-bastion-host
    HostName <IP_of_your_bastion_host_on_EC2>
    Port 22
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<your_key_file_for_bastion_host>.pem
    ForwardAgent yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Using a Bastion host and a VPC, you are able to connect to the AWS Elasticache service by SSH port forwarding...

```
ssh your-bastion-host -Cv -N -L 6390:ec-replication-group-xyz.amazonaws.com:6379
```

..and "redis-cli" tool (It makes sense to forward the Redis port 6379 to a different port locally if you already have a Redis server installed locally)

```
redis-cli -h localhost -p 6390 
info
monitor
```

Then you can use in "redis-cli" the **monitor** command to display every command processed by the Redis server and the **info** command to get the most important information and statistics about the Redis server.